# Invarinte de boucle pour monter exactitude d un algorithme

Tags: algorithm

Bonjour  Svp je veux une méthode simple comment déterminer invariante de boucle pour montrer que un algorithme est exacte
Please have you a simple method how determinate the loop invariante To demontrate that an algorith is correct ?

Comment: Мадемуазель, я полагаю, что не все смогут понять Ваш вопрос об инварианте цикла. You'd better to write in English

Comment: Ok have you a simple method how determinate the loop invariante To demontrate that an algorith is correct ?

Comment: I put it in 2 language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too broad question. You have to use concrete algorithm and show that some property is valid before and after every turn of algorithm loop.

For example, you can show for [Insertion Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) that first K elements of array are sorted after K-1 loops.

Comment: I know that but i always choose a false one besides the demonstration in itself is already a problem

Comment: Again - there is no 'silver bullet' suitable for all cases. One should explore concrete algortihm and figure out what is invariant for it

Comment: Anyway thank you for answering :)